# Where is Remove Double Vertices blender 2.9 Alpha

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

The First image is mine, The Second image is Teacher of Tutorial. I tried find out "Remove Double Vertices" But I can't find it out anywhere. Where is it in Blender 2.9 Alpha?

Answer (score 7):

The *Remove double vertices* operator has been move into the "Mesh" menu and is now executed by going *Merge > By Distance*. Note that you can access it by right clicking while in edit mode and vertex select mode.

[image]